# SSRS - Display Blank Values

Tags: reporting-services

## Parameter Values

[image]

---

I am trying to display all the records with any status. When the user select 'AllLogs' from the dropdwon in report.

1. But when I run the report it is excluding the records with blank
   status.
2. How can i pull the records with any status(blank,NULL,Approved,etc) ?

   Label: Status
   Value: %
3. I have also enabled NULL and Blank values in the parameter properties.

This is my where clause.

```
 ( ( l.Status LIKE '%' + @status + '%' ) OR
          ( l.Status LIKE @status ) OR
          ( LTRIM(RTRIM(l.Status))='') OR
          ( l.status IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: in your where clause you can add `... or status is null or status = ''`

Comment: This is my where clause. It did not work.
@alejandrozuleta
where ( ( l.Status LIKE '%' + status + '%' ) OR
              ( l.Status LIKE status ) OR
              ( status = '' ) OR
              ( status IS NULL ) )

Comment: I'd check if status column has whitespaces only. `LTRIM(RTRIM(l.Status))=''`. Also your WHERE clause is wrong  in your question. `l.Status = '' OR l.Status is null` you are using the parameter value instead.

Comment: I tried your recommendation.But the blank values are still excluded in my report when I select the AllLogs label with % value in my report.@alejandrozuleta

Comment: Based on the image you added, I'd create a dataset that run conditionally two selects: if parameter = 'All' then select * from table else select * from table where status = @parameter, adjust it to SQL syntax if that sounds like a possible solution. Also chage the 'All Logs' label value to 'All'.

Answer (score 0):

The most surefire way to include all records is to simply not filter in your `where`, which can be achieved with a short-circuiting `case` statement:

```
where case when @status = '%'  -- This can be any value, such as 'All'
           then 1
           else case when l.Status = @status
                     then 1
                     else 0
                     end
           end = 1
```

Whilst this is a little verbose, it has the added benefit of not actually running the comparison if your `All` option is selected, which will improve query performance.